# Intltool: Automake version mismatch

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install intltool, but I am getting this error:

```
error: version mismatch.  This is Automake 1.14.1,
configure.ac:7: but the definition used by this AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
configure.ac:7: comes from Automake 1.14.  You should recreate
configure.ac:7: aclocal.m4 with aclocal and run automake again."
```

Before I was having the error for 1.11.1, then I removed `aclocal.m4` and ran     `aclocal` and it made it again and now its 1.14 apparently. But I still get the error. How do I fix this?

```
    dnl Process this file with autoconf to create configure.
AC_PREREQ([2.53])

AC_INIT([intltool], [0.50.2])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([intltoolize.in])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])

pkgdatadir='${datadir}'"/${PACKAGE}"
AC_SUBST(pkgdatadir) dnl automake does not need this, but libtoolize does
aclocaldir='${datadir}'/aclocal
AC_SUBST(aclocaldir)

AC_PATH_PROG(PERL, perl)
if test -z "$PERL"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([perl not found])
fi
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for perl >= 5.8.1])
$PERL -e "use 5.8.1;" > /dev/null 2>&1
if test $? -ne 0; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([perl 5.8.1 is required for intltool])
else
   PERL_VERSION="`$PERL -e \"printf '%vd', $^V\"`"
   AC_MSG_RESULT([$PERL_VERSION])
fi
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for XML::Parser])
if `$PERL -e "require XML::Parser" 2>/dev/null`; then
   AC_MSG_RESULT([ok])
else
   AC_MSG_ERROR([XML::Parser perl module is required for intltool])
fi
AC_PATH_PROG(BZR, bzr)


AC_CONFIG_FILES([
Makefile
doc/Makefile
intltoolize
tests/Makefile
tests/cases/Makefile
tests/results/Makefile
tests/selftest.pl
])

AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: What's in your `configure.ac`? Preferably, [edit] the question to provide this information.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error while compiling libx11 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I fixed it by running `autoreconf`, and then rerunning `./configure && make`

```
autoreconf
./configure
make
```